# I have a very big list of dictionaries and I want to sum the insides

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

Something like

```
{A: 3, 45, 34, 4, 2, 5, 94, 2139, 230345, 283047, 230847}, {B: 92374, 324, 345, 345, 45879, 34857987, 3457938457), {C: 23874923874987, 2347}
```

How can I reduce that to

```
{A: 2304923094820398}, {B: 2374923784897}, {C: 29348239847239847}
```

Values obviously not exact. I just want to add up all the values in a non-time consuming manner.

Comment: "Something like"? We can't give an exact answer without an exact structure.

Comment: That's the exact structure. Numbers are just different.

Comment: @Fred-Wilson - hope not, that is not valid python syntax

Comment: big lists of things take longer to sum up than smaller lists of things simple as that. Summing a list of numbers in Python is best done with the sum() function. If the sum() function isn't fast enough you could try writing a C extension or using numpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = [{'A': [3, 45, 34, 4, 2, 5, 94, 2139, 230345, 283047, 230847]}, {'B': [92374, 324, 345, 345, 45879, 34857987, 3457938457]}, {'C': [23874923874987, 2347]}]
[{x.keys()[0]:sum(x.values()[0])} for x in d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
a={'a':range(100), 'b':range(200)}
b={}

for k,v in a.iteritems():
    b[k]=sum(v)

print b
```

gives

```
{'a': 4950, 'b': 19900}
```

Comment: My try was essentially this. For some reason it keeps giving me an error. Is this specific to Python 3 because I am using 2.7.

Comment: I'm using 2.7. There is an error in your data structure, numbers needs to be enclosed by `[]`  i.e. in a list.

Comment: They are enclosed by that... perhaps I made a typographical error. This SHOULD work, as I copypasted it into my version of python and it ran.

Comment: @Fred Wilson: "For some reason it keeps giving me an error"  That's why we ask for (1) actual code and (2) the actual error.  Please **update** the question with both.  We can't guess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are in a list,  like:

```
d = {A: [3, 45, 34, 4, 2, 5, 94, 2139, 230345, 283047, 230847]}, {B: [92374, 324, 345, 345, 45879, 34857987, 3457938457]), {C: [23874923874987, 2347]}
```

then:

```
new_d = []
for i in d:
    new_d.append(dict([(k,sum(v)) for k,v in i.itervalues()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots and lots and lots of values, something like this might work (assuming by "list of dictionaries" you mean "dictionary of lists", as having a big list of one-key/value-pair dictionaries would be silly, and thus the values are stored in a `dict` like `{'A': [3, 45, 34, 4, 2, 5, 94, 2139, 230345, 283047, 230847], 'B': [92374, 324, 345, 345, 45879, 34857987, 3457938457], ...}`):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def sumfunc(lock, key, values):
    total = sum(values)

    lock.acquire()
    print(key + ':', total)   # The actual code would be better off utilizing shared multiprocessing.Array objects, but I haven't used them before so am not sure quite how you set them up so decided to leave that aside for now as this is just a theoretical example.
    lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    for key, values in dict_of_values_to_sum.items():
        Process(target=sumfunc, args=(lock, key, values)).start()
```

Comment: @Fred: You specifically asked for a non-time-consuming solution. If you have a large number of values to sum a large number of times, and the sums don't affect each other, it might be better to process them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a real big number of values i'll probably use numpy and do a vector addition.

So, something like

```
 a = numpy.arange(10, 2000000)
 total = numpy.sum(a)
```

Nothing more, nothing less :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = [{'A': [3, 45, 34, 4, 2, 5, 94, 2139, 230345, 283047, 230847]}, {'B': [92374, 324, 345, 345, 45879, 34857987, 3457938457]}, {'C': [23874923874987, 2347]}]
abc = {}
for x in d:
    for k, v in x.iteritems():
        abc[k] = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, v)
```