# sum of one value in the list of dictionary based on one key in dict

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to sum one value in the list of dictionary based on another key value is equal.

stackOverflow much easier question answer for just sum the total value:
[I have a very big list of dictionaries and I want to sum the insides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602678/i-have-a-very-big-list-of-dictionaries-and-i-want-to-sum-the-insides)

For example: if we have

```
lst = [{'year': 2013, 'snow': 64.8, 'month': 1},
       {'year': 2013, 'snow': 66.5, 'month': 2},
       {'year': 2013, 'snow': 68.3, 'month': 12},
       {'year': 2013, 'snow': 68.8, 'month': 3},
       {'year': 2013, 'snow': 70.9, 'month': 11},
       {'year': 2012, 'snow': 76.8, 'month': 7},
       {'year': 2012, 'snow': 79.6, 'month': 5},
       {'year': 1951, 'snow': 86.6, 'month': 12}]
```

to get the sum of snow fall in that year:

**the output** should:

```
snowfall = [{'year': 2013, 'totalsnow': 339.3},
            {'year': 2012, 'totalsnow': 156.4},
            {'year': 1951, 'totalsnow': 86.6}]
```

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
        while lst[i]['year']:
            sum(value['snow'] for value in lst)
```

then it will goes wrong, output

```
582.3000000000001
```

How to get it right? Please be sample and explain as well. I am new to python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dictionary to track snow-per-year; a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is ideal here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

snowfall = defaultdict(float)

for info in lst:
    snowfall[info['year']] += info['snow']

snowfall = [{'year': year, 'totalsnow': snowfall[year]} 
            for year in sorted(snowfall, reverse=True)]
```

This first creates a `defaultdict()` object that'll create new `float()` objects (value 0.0) for keys that don't exist yet. It sums the values per year for you.

The last lines create your desired structure, sorted by year in descending order.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = [{'year': 2013, 'snow': 64.8, 'month': 1},
...        {'year': 2013, 'snow': 66.5, 'month': 2},
...        {'year': 2013, 'snow': 68.3, 'month': 12},
...        {'year': 2013, 'snow': 68.8, 'month': 3},
...        {'year': 2013, 'snow': 70.9, 'month': 11},
...        {'year': 2012, 'snow': 76.8, 'month': 7},
...        {'year': 2012, 'snow': 79.6, 'month': 5},
...        {'year': 1951, 'snow': 86.6, 'month': 12}]
>>> snowfall = defaultdict(float)
>>> for info in lst:
...     snowfall[info['year']] += info['snow']
... 
>>> snowfall = [{'year': year, 'totalsnow': snowfall[year]} 
...             for year in sorted(snowfall, reverse=True)]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(snowfall)
[{'totalsnow': 339.30000000000007, 'year': 2013},
 {'totalsnow': 156.39999999999998, 'year': 2012},
 {'totalsnow': 86.6, 'year': 1951}]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you your help. I didn't mean to be sorted, so if I delete last line, raise "NameError: name 'year' is not defined". Which is make sense because the for loop is gone. So I re make the loop. I change the last line to "for year in snowfall" It does not work. eh:( I am not so smart in programming ...

Comment: @MarquisRandell: replace `sorted(snowfall, reverse=True)` with just `snowfall` instead; you still need the loop: `[{'year': year, 'totalsnow': snowfall[year]} for year in snowfall]`.

Comment: Yes it works again. but the list looks sorted. Is that because the defaultdict? could me make not sorted? If is the way it is, that is fine.

Comment: If the order is sorted, then that's a coincidence. Dictionaries have no ordering, but you *are* creating a list which does have order.